# JavaScript Array Not Receiving Info in Console

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a JS application that will pull information from a web form to create an account ID on the users first and last initials and then add all account info into array. The generation of my account ID works but when I go into my browser console I just get a return of [] for the array. Here is the exact instructions for the array: Add another statement declaring a global variable named newAccountArray with an empty array as its value.

Here is my code:

```
    'use strict';

 var newAccountArray = [];

 function createID(){
   var fname = document.getElementById("fnameinput");
   var lname = document.getElementById("lnameinput");
   var zip = document.getElementById("zipinput");
   var account = document.getElementById("accountidbox");
   var fields = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
   var acctid;
   var firstInit;
   var lastInit;

   if( fname !== " " && lname !== " " && zip !== " "){
     firstInit = fname.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
     lastInit = lname.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
     acctid = firstInit + lastInit + zip.value;
     account.value = acctid;
     newAccountArray = [];
     for(var i = 0; i < fields.length -1; i++){
       newAccountArray.push(fields[i].value);
     }
   }

 }

 function createEventListeners(){
   var fname = document.getElementById("fnameinput");
   var lname = document.getElementById("lnameinput");
   var zip = document.getElementById("zipinput");
   if(fname.addEventListener){
     fname.addEventListener("change", createID, false);
     lname.addEventListener("change", createID, false);
     zip.addEventListener("change", createID, false);
   }else if(fname.attachEvent) {
     fname.attachEvent("onchange", createID);
     lname.attachEvent("onchange", createID);
     zip.attachEvent("onchange", createID);

   }
 }

 if(window.addEventListener){
   window.addEventListener("load", createEventListeners, false);
 }else if(window.attachEvent){
   window.attachEvent("onload", createEventListeners);
 }
```

Comment: Quick observation: IF your `field` array has only one value, then `newAccountArray.push(fields[i].value);` never gets run. Reason? You've told the containing loop to terminate when `i < array.length - 1` i.e. when `i = 0`, which also happens to be your start condition. So your for loop wouldn't execute.

Comment: That is how the text book said to enter it.... Exactly. So what should I change it to?

Comment: Change it to 'i < fields.length'. Two character change. This may or may not solve your problem, but it's worth correcting at least.

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
       newAccountArray.push(fields[i].value);
     }

Comment: That is what I changed it to so we are on the same page?